# Encoding filename for Nginx Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, nginx, freebsd

I have requests to `UTF-8` urls like this :

```
http://www.example.com:8080/pk/s/151x120/%D8%A2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9.jpg
```

I stock the result in a file with filename :

```
%D8%A2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9.jpg
```

But nginx doesn't seem to see the cache and redo the same request. I have found that nginx do load this kind of `UTF-8` filename :

```
\341\203\250\341\203.jpg
```

But, I don't remember either the name of the encoding or the ruby method to produce filename like this... :(

Using : Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2, Nginx and FreeBSD

Comment: No one knows the name of the enconding ? :(

Comment: I don't know that encoding type, but it kind of looks like a byte array: `"%D8%A2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9".unpack("U*")`

Comment: You could always base64 encode the filename as well so you'd have alphanumeric filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to unescape the [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> URI.unescape "http://www.example.com:8080/pk/s/151x120/%D8%A2%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9.jpg"
=> "http://www.example.com:8080/pk/s/151x120/\330\242\331\210\330\247\330\262-\332\251.jpg"
```